# Does mixing javascript functions and Cypress commands contribute to test flakiness?

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

Among many, One of my test looks like

```
it("Admin is able to edit new group", () => {
    cy.intercept("PUT", /\/api\/groups/).as("editGroupAPI");
    cy.get("@groups").then(groups => {
      const group = groups[0];
      // go to edit page cancel and come back to groups page
      app.groupsPage.card
        .groupActionIcon(group.name, "modify")
        .scrollIntoView()
        .click();
      app.commonElements
        .toolBarTitle()
        .should("have.text", "Edit Group");
      app.groupsPage.groupDetailsForm.cancelButton().click();
      app.commonElements.toolBarTitle().should("have.text", "Groups");
      // edit group - 1
      app.groupsPage.card
        .groupActionIcon(group.name, "modify")
        .scrollIntoView()
        .click();
      app.groupsPage.groupDetailsForm
        .groupDescription()
        .type(" edited");
      app.groupsPage.groupDetailsForm.saveButton().click();
      cy.wait("@editGroupAPI");
      // validate that Groups page have loaded
      app.commonElements.toolBarTitle().should("have.text", "Groups");
      // validate whether group card description is reflected on card
      app.groupsPage.card
        .groupDescription(group.name)
        .should("have.text", group.description + " edited");
    });
  });
```

*app is top level parent obj, and this test uses Page Object Model.*

One example of POM class is :

```
class CommonElements {
  burgerMenu() {
    return cy.get("#widgets-banner-appBanner-sideDrawerButton-content");
  }
  toolBarTitle() {
    return cy.get("h1.app-toolbar__title__main-title");
  }
  toolBarTitleWithText(text) {
    return cy.contains("h1.app-toolbar__title__main-title", text);
  }
  globalScopeButton() {
    return cy.get("#global-scope-switch-toggleSwitch-button");
  }
}
```

So as it is evident that, cy.wait() and then call to pageObjectModel function to grab title element:

```
cy.wait("@editGroupAPI");
// validate that Groups page have loaded
app.commonElements.toolBarTitle().should("have.text", "Groups");
```

Now sometimes this fails, so as I have seen in docs, plain js code get executed immediately, but since in this case whole test is wrapped in cy.get("alias"), will it still matter (or execute js immediately)?

This might sound very obvious, but I just want to confirm.

**Final question: does mix usage of Page Object Model functions and cy.command contribute to test flakiness?**

Comment: Using POM on its own does not contribute to flakiness, but not understanding the way in which your POM can interact with Cypress probably does. I'd check out this great write-up on using app actions vs. POM -> https://applitools.com/blog/page-objects-app-actions-cypress/

Comment: I have read this blog, but in here POM is used to share element selection logic. Also updated question with one POM class example

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, mixing Cypress commands with Page Object model functions does not itself contribute to test flakiness.

Explanation: a Cypress command is never executed immediately. It does not matter if a Cypress command is called in any 'external' function (including a POM function) or directly in a test case function. Either way, Cypress commands are only enqueued when statements of a function are executed. And they later will be executed in the same order regardless whether they defined inside 'external' function or test case one.

This is also true for a command that was called inside a cypress synchronous block of code (in a *then*/*should* callback). Even in this case the command will not be executed immediately.

In a nutshell, using a POM function to call a Cypress command does not influence on how and when this command is executed and so using POM approach can not itself contribute to any test flakiness.

You can play and see the order of command execution using such a script:
[image]
You can either open Dev console to see the console output or use breakpoints to see the execution live.
The gif above shows the debugging directly from IDE (IntelliJ) using the Cypress Support Pro plugin

Comment: thank you bro, I forgot to check your answer, I guess you are right, but still since some of my tests are failing, I'll check and come back.